# How to save a quiver plot

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, while-loop

Let me show you my code

```
array['fieldv'].shape
```

```
(112, 750, 750, 2)
```

and if I a plot an element, this image appear

```
%matplotlib inline
U, V  = array['fieldv'][10,:,:,0], array['fieldv'][10,:,:,1]
plt.quiver(U[::4,::4], V[::4, ::4])
```

[image]

Now my question is: how can I save in a directory all the quiver lots of the 112 elements?
I show you my code that doesn't work

```
%matplotlib inline

i = 0
while i != len(array['fieldv'][0]):
    U, V  = array['fieldv'][i:,:,0], array['fieldv'][i,:,:,1]
    fig = plt.quiver(U[::4,::4], V[::4, ::4])

    filename = '/home/rr/workspace/TEST/OUTPUT/vectorf/'
    fig.savefig(filename + 'TEST_' + str(i) + '.png')
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.quiver` does not return a Figure instance (check `type(fig)` and you'll see that `plt.quiver` actually creates an instance of Quiver). The Quiver object does not have a `savefig` method and so `fig.savefig` will not work. However, you should just be able to swap the the `fig.savefig` command with `plt.savefig`.

As a more general comment I think it's more appropriate to use a for loop here, rather than a while statment. I'd do so as `for i in range (array['fieldv'].shape[0]):`. I also think `.format` is a bit neater: `plt.savefig('{}TEST_{}.png'.format(filename, i))`.

Putting that altogether I'd do:

```
filename = '/home/rr/workspace/TEST/OUTPUT/vectorf/'

for i in range(array['fieldv'].shape[0]):
    U, V  = array['fieldv'][i:,:,0], array['fieldv'][i,:,:,1]
    Q = plt.quiver(U[::4,::4], V[::4, ::4])

    plt.savefig('{}TEST_{}.png'.format(filename, i))
```